# from what C++ libraries 'vbprintf' is it coming?

Tags: c++

I try to compile a program developed by someone else, and to do so I have to link some libraries, it's what I did. But once I try to compile I have the following error message:

```
/tmp/ccGVkdZ4.o: In function `main':
furian_main.c:(.text.startup+0x256): undefined reference to `vbprintf'
/mnt/c/.../furian-1.0/libfurian.a(furian.o): In function `furian':
furian.c:(.text+0x111c): undefined reference to `vbprintf'
furian.c:(.text+0x3223): undefined reference to `vbprintf'
furian.c:(.text+0x3a62): undefined reference to `vbprintf'
furian.c:(.text+0x3aca): undefined reference to `vbprintf'
/mnt/c/Users/matth/Desktop/cesure_1/cesure_fourier/furian-1.0/libfurian.a(furian.o):furian.c:(.text+0x3bcd): more undefined references to `vbprintf' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'furian_main' failed
make: *** [furian_main] Error 1
```

I guess that the library with 'vbprintf' has been badly linked, but I don't know from which library it's coming.

EDIT: it's coming from lib abz, but now the question is how to install this library, I found no information on Google.

Can someone help me on this point?

thank you

Comment: [Literally the first Google result](https://manned.org/vbprintf): `abz` or `debug`.

Comment: ok fine, but how do I install it now ? those library are not in my program and i don't fine any information on google on how to install it

Comment: You can download the source version from here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libabz/0.7.2+nmu1 but I would highly recommend that you just remove that dependency and replace it with something else. It's deliberately designed to be thread unsafe and there's a reason that package was removed from debian and ubutunu

Comment: ok thank you, I don't think I will multi thread my program so it's not a real problem for now, but if I could avoid installing a new library I would be glad yes. But I don't know with what I could replace... maybe `cout` ? but I'll have to recode everything and it's also thread insafe if I don't mistake

Comment: just manage a few local buffers and use `vsnprintf` or something like it. If it's just for priting then why even bother printing to buffers then just straight up use `vprintf`

Comment: Oh and since you tagged this C++ rather than C you could also consider something like [`fmtlib`](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)